# Calculating a series based on a parameter

Tags: calculus

From my textbook:

> Calculate: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{10n^2}{n^3+k^3}$$

The problem is that I don't understand what they mean by 'calculate'. It looks like from WolframAlpha that it does not have a nice closed formula. So do they mean to just show that the series is diverges? If so, How can I do it?

Comment: There’s something missing about $k$ ?

Comment: @marwalix nothing is said about it. I guess $k\in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think that you have to show that it diverges (informally, the sum of the given series is $+\infty$).

Hint. Given any real $k$ (but not a negative integer), consider the following inequality valid for any positive integer $n$ such that $n> k$,
$$\frac{10n^2}{n^3+k^3}> \frac{10n^2}{n^3+n^3}=\frac{5}{n}.$$
Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{10n^2}{n^3+k^3}=
\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{10n^2}{n^3+k^3}+\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{10n^2}{n^3+k^3}\geq
\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{10n^2}{n^3+k^3}+5\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: what if $n \leq k$?

Comment: @vesii See my edit.

Comment: @vesii Note that convergence only depends on terms $n>N$ for any $N$. That is to say, the convergence of a series does not depend on the first $N$ terms.